# Is WMC0011 issued because the the C++/WinRT Xaml Compiler does not yet deal with element tags?

Tags: xaml, c++-winrt

*Xaml excerpt:*
<local:EditOrientationRadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" EditOrientationTag="Left"               Checked="OnOrientationRadioButtonChecked"

*C++/WinRT excerpt:*
radioButton.EditOrientationTag();

*Xaml Compiler output:*
XamlCompiler error WMC0011: Unknown member EditOrientationTag' on element 'EditOrientationRadioButton'

Comment: This question is apparently asking for several different things and it's hard to make out what they are. Please see [ask].

Comment: Please check if your EditOrientationRadioButton has declare  `EditOrientationTag` dependency property.

Comment: Do you solve the problem, and any updates for this problem?

Comment: Yes your suggestion led to a solution. I need to filter Xaml Compiler WMC**** error messages and look for the underlying causes.

Comment: May I converter the comments as the answer for this case, and you could also post your solution by self.

Comment: The code is too large to copy and paste so I will try to add as a zip file.

Comment: You have not need paste complete code, you could explain your solution and paste segment code below.